# Can't get email from authenticated user with Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's Facebook Login to authenticate my users. I had to upgrade my project to Firebase 3.x thus I had to change this bit. I achieved getting 'fullname' with `user!.displayName` and 'photoUrl' with `user!.photoUrl`for example; but cannot access email with `user!.email` even though 'email' scope is set.

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self, handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
    if facebookError != nil {
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
    } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {
        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Login failed. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Logged in!")
                print(user!.displayName) // works
                print(user!.photoUrl)    // works
                print(user!.email)       // returns nil
            }
        })
    }
```

I am pretty sure the email is valid because it used to fetch the email just fine before I upgraded to Firebase 3.x. I also tried multiple Facebook accounts but no luck. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when migrating to Firebase Auth 3.x from a previous version of Firebase Auth. It is related to being able to create multiple accounts with the same email address in previous versions. For more information please take a look at this related [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/181).

In order to fix it you need to `Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address` in the Auth section of the Firebase console:

Here is a screenshot showing the option in the Firebase console.

[image: Console Screenshot.]

Comment: No prob! happy coding!